# Array to treeview node

Tags: android, arrays, treeview

i have `ArrayList<String> Array1`
and i want to add to my treeview

```
List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        TreeNode<Dir> app = new TreeNode<>(new Dir("app"));
        nodes.add(app);
        app.addChild(
                new TreeNode<>(new Dir("AA01")));
        app.addChild(
                new TreeNode<>(new Dir("AA02")));
        app.addChild(
                new TreeNode<>(new Dir("AA03")));
```

but it's manually, i try like this

```
List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        TreeNode<Dir> app = new TreeNode<>(new Dir("app"));
        nodes.add(app);
        app.addChild(
                new TreeNode<>(new Dir(Array1)));
```

but error

[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9mH4.png)

how to adding my array to my code without error, Array1 = [AA01,AA02,AA03]

Comment: Please add the error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a String as an argument for the Dir constructor when in fact it should receive an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

As Androidz said you provides the wrong argument type. You provides an array of string instead of a simple string.

You can't do that. If you don't want to add them manually you have to loop through the array.

```
//loop Array1 and get all the strings 1 by 1
for(String s : Array1) {
    //add the string to the node
    app.addChild(new TreeNode<>(new Dir(s)));
}
```

Comment: your array `Array1` is not initialized. You have to put values inside before being able to loop it.